# Admob Ads impressions issue

Tags: android, admob, impressions

Admob network details

This is last 28 days data from admob of my Android app, I'm using Admob in this app from last 3 years. Everything was fine till this Jan but after that no impressions but have ad requests. I didn't get any email nor any policy violation in policy center nor I updated my this app. Suddenly ads impressions falls to zero without any warning. Rest of the apps ads are okay and no problem in ads placement too. Need help regarding this issue.

Admob network performance:
[image: Admob network performance]

Policy center:
[image: Policy center]

Answer (score 0):

Its happening with me too don’t know what is wrong with adMob. Its been 2 weeks since i have launched my application. [image]

Comment: Your case is fine because your "Match rate" is 100.00%. You should check the implementation of your ads.

Answer (score 0):

1. As per your screenshot of Ad Data there are many requests, but match rate is very low. Generally it is around 90-100%.
2. Check your implementation and update as per best practices given by google. Important in Ad is : Control on Ad request.
3. Check all user path, and do request accordingly, Use Analytics, Events to check how user is using your app and after request ad , is it presenting or not
4. change placement of ad according to the data of analytics